# Integrating Doctrine in CodeIgniter 3 - entity error

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

im new in Doctrine. Im trying to integrate Doctrine in my CodeIgniter instance but i get an error:

> Class "User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

The entity User was ceated automatically and looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $uid;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cr_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $crDate = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
```

eaccelerator is disabled in my php.ini file and was loaded.

Doctrine knows the correct path in its config.

The backtrace looks like this:

> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php
>   Line: 89 Function: classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass
>
> File:
>   /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 117 Function: loadMetadataForClass
>
> File:
>   /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 332 Function: doLoadMetadata
>
> File:
>   /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 216 Function: loadMetadata
>
> File:
>   /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   Line: 360 Function: getMetadataFor
>
> File: /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/models/Usermodel.php Line: 36
>   Function: find
>
> File: /var/www/dadgehog/ci/application/controllers/Login.php Line: 23
>   Function: getUser
>
> File: /var/www/dadgehog/index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

If anyone has an idea to point that out, i would be happy.

Comment: Is `User.php` controller?

Comment: User.php is an entity. It is stored in the folder application/models/entities. The related model is Usermodel.php, in which i try to get access to the magic method find of the entity manager of Doctrine

Comment: What documentation you followed to integrate Doctrine? 
Have you tried [these steps](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html)?

Comment: Yes i used the official one. In a blog i found the hint to the EntityGenerator to auto create all entities of my db

Comment: i figured it out a bit. I debugged the Doctrine file parser. It can't read the annotations correctly. But the file seems to be ok in the first view.

DocParser::Annotations just iterates through the file without any hit of an annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official guide](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html) is not complete, and [others](https://www.google.it/search?q=install%20doctrine%20in%20codeigniter) are for CI2.

I made this tutorial on SO for CI3:

[How to install Doctrine in CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209930/how-to-install-doctrine-in-codeigniter-3/33209931#33209931)